# how to check value of stored variable in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I want to get stored value and assert that value. But currently am not able to assert that value.I have tried following way,

```
selenium.storeAllButtons("var1");
selenium.verifyAllButtons("${var1}",selenium.getAllButtons());
```

But above assertion fails.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no method "storeAllButtons" in WebDriver java code bindings.

What you'll have to do is make a list of elements like:

```
List<WebElement> items = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("button"));
```

Then you'll have to iterate your list and make assertion on each element that meets your expectation.